# Make flexbox children with same height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox parent setted with flex-direction: row. 
Inside this parent, I have two children. I would like them to have the same height!

Inside this children I have dynamic content (with variable height).

The way I'm doing, if I add text on the right child, the left one will grow. 
But If the left child grows, the right one stays small.

Should not they behave in the same way?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4g6uevok/8/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">MY TITLE:</div>
    <div class="left-area">

      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">#1</div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">#2</div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">#3</div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">AC</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="title">SECOND TITLE:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: red;
}

.left{
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;     
    background:lime;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.title {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:#525252;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "emir-bold";
}

.left-area {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.left-area-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-area-row-titulo {
    width: 49.5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #819196;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    margin:0 2px 4px 0;
}
.left-area-row-info {
    width: 49.5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 6px;
    margin:0 0 4px 2px;
}

.right {
    width: calc(100% - 430px);
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background:orange;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Lots of children in your example. Can you make the issue obvious in the fiddle ?

Comment: The problem is due to the children! Removing them entails no problem appearing! Basically, what I am trying is that the orange DIV stays the same height as the lime DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex items are aligned to `strech` by default. Your `height:100%` value in `.right` class preventing it to take whole height so try to remove `height:100%` to the `.right` element

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lime;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #525252;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "emir-bold";
}

.left-area {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left-area-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-area-row-titulo {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #819196;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 2px 4px 0;
}

.left-area-row-info {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 0 4px 2px;
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 430px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: orange;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">MY TITLE:</div>
    <div class="left-area">
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">
          #1
        </div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">
          #2
        </div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">BA</div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">
          #3
        </div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">C</div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-area-row">
        <div class="left-area-row-titulo">
          #4
        </div>
        <div class="left-area-row-info">D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="title">SECOND TITLE:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the light! Works perfectly!